# changing images asynchronously in WPF

Tags: wpf, sockets

I am sending WriteableBitmap images as bytes[] to WPF application over network sockets asynchronously .how can i change the images in WPF image control that seems to be like live streaming..?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for -

http://dotnetlearning.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/loading-images-asynchronously-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks Dor Cohen for the reply,but my requirement is , I am sending WriteableBitmap images as bytes[] from my windows phone over local network to a paricular IP. i want to convert those bytes again to WriteableBitmap images and need to show in WPF windows.